# How do you use intelliJ .http ? (sending formdata with intellij http request)

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, request, multipartform-data

[IntelliJ request code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UGNF.png)

I want sending formdata with intelliJ http request.
The formdata contains images and string values.

[postman test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVUY0.png)
[postman test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ji51.png)

postman test very well.
but intelliJ http request has an error.

I think there is an error because the request can only receive the json format.

If I'm right, how do I change the data to json?

If I'm wrong, please let me know how I can send the format data through the .http document in Intellij.

this is error message.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/article

HTTP/1.1 500 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 21 Dec 2021 13:19:07 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "timestamp": "2021-12-21T13:19:07.631+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "path": "/article"
}

Response code: 500; Time: 247ms; Content length: 108 bytes
```

this is request code.

```
### user posting
POST http://localhost:8080/article
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------350706080748288521853915
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0MSIsImV4cCI6MTY0MDEwNzA1NiwiaWF0IjoxNjQwMDg5MDU2fQ.bOQBrXklT1K8X9wZWJPaIzMG6TKOg-YKWUqhEqkPVix2cF5mdVIJZODrZ3-JxwPcJD5iqSNIP9t-_vHy24grnQ

--------------------------350706080748288521853915
image : < /Users/macbookpro/IdeaProjects/timeattack/src/main/resources/static/overloading.jpg
title : this is title
content: this is content...
userid: 1
tag : bbs,java,omg
--------------------------350706080748288521853915--
```

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

omg..
I'm a fool for not using official documents.
I ask a question and I answer.
If you use the boundary, you can send multipart/form-data.
So I succeeded in sending photos and text to the IntelliJ api document. Without a postman.
This is the official guide.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

this is *.http document* of intellij.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/article
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0MiIsImV4cCI6MTY0MDEyMTAwMywiaWF0IjoxNjQwMTAzMDAzfQ.FzftaHsGqkg43KxmV2KdaBWUkhLhGygAY6b1YUQyQ3ypYG2wSuwz_hVPkZfdjjXzhgRgpF9pXAptUZXU9p5UWw

-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575
content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="overloading.jpg"
Content-Type: text/plain

< /Users/macbookpro/IdeaProjects/timeattack/src/main/resources/static/joincolumn.jpg
-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575
content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
Content-Type: text/plain

test text
-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575--
```

Comment: IN case you need to pass object, then 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="yourObject"
Content-Type: application/json

{